# Question on Sequences and limits

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If sequence {$a_n$} satisfies $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} (2n-1)a_n=40$, what is the value of $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty}na_n$ ?

Any hints ?

Comment: Hint: $(2n-1)a_n=na_n(2-1/n)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$na_n=\dfrac{n}{2n-1}.(2n-1)a_n\to \frac{1}{2}.40=20$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (2n-1)a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} 2na_n - a_n = 2\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n - \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$$

What would happen if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \neq 0$?

Comment: Why should $a_n \to 0$ ? Can't $a_n \to some other constant$ ?

Comment: @square_one: If that was the case, then $n a_n$ can't have a finite limit as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Semiclassical More preciselly, $(2n-1)a_n$ wouldn't have a finite limit as $n\to \infty$ wich we know isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

By definition of limit there is some integer $m>1$ such that for any $n>m$ we have : $$39<(2n-1)a_n<41$$ Then $$\forall\ n>m,\ \ \frac{39}{2n-1} <a_n< \frac{41}{2n-1} $$ Then $a_n\to 0$ and therefore $2na_n\to 40$ which leads to $na_n\to 20$.

Comment: @Shane I had a typo in the first line.

Comment: Why should $a_n \to 0$ ? Can't $a_n \to some other constant$ ?

Comment: @square_one note that $a_n$ is bounded by two sequences that tend to $0$ then it tend to $0$ as well (the squeeze theorem).

Comment: My Bad. I failed to see that the two sides are actually zeros.. I was looking at them as 39 and 41 ..